# Recovering Single User Single Machine Mercurial repositories

Tags: windows, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I use Mercurial (from Tortoise HG) on Windows as a Single User, Single Machine Version Control system. I had the directories of all my repositories backed up.

On a new machine, I copied back the directories. I also installed THG. THG doesn't seem to recognise the directories as repositories on it's own. i.e. in Explorer I don't see the checked out/committed icons on the file names. If I right click on a file, and go to the THG options, it does show me revision history etc. When I do open Repository on THG and point it to the directories, it does again show info.

How do I make it see the dir as a repository from Windows Explorer.

Also I haven't yet tried changing files, committing etc, no idea if it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your only 'problem' is that you don't see the overlay icons in the Windows explorer shell. Otherwise everything's ok.

You can try to simply close/reopen explorer. If that doesn't work, a system restart will do in any case.